# Linear transformations - 2 opposite claims, solution attempt included

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V, W$ are vector spaces and $ T: V \to W $  is a linear transformation.

$v_1, v_2, ... , v_k \in V$.

Prove or disprove:

- If  $span( v_1, v_2, ... , v_k) = V$, then $span(T(v_1), ... , T(v_k) = W$.
- If $span(T(v_1), ... , T(v_k)) = W$, then $span( v_1, v_2, ... , v_k) = V$.

My solution goes:

- The first claim is false. let $, V, W = \mathbb R$, and $ T: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. We define $T$ as $T(v) = 0$, and $v_1 = [1]$. Therefore, $span(v_1) =\mathbb R$, but $span(T(v_1)) = span(0) \neq \mathbb R$.
- Second claim: We can easily prove that if $(T(v_1),...,T(v_n))$ is linearly independent, then $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent as well. Is this enough to conclude that since we know $span(T(v_1), ... , T(v_k)) = W$, then $T(v_1), ... , T(v_k)$ is linearly independent, therefore $ v_1, v_2, ... , v_k$ is linearly independent, and thus  $span( v_1, v_2, ... , v_k) = V$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changed it, the question remains the same. Cant figure out how to prove or disprove the second claim.

Comment: What if $\dim V\gt\dim W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you did great. For the second consider $W=\{0\}$

Comment: How is this a counter example?

Comment: What I mean, if the empty set spans W, what could possibly be my T?

Comment: @Tegernako: The point is that if $W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ (so your $T$ is the zero map), then any collection $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ will satisfy that $\mathrm{span}(T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_k)) = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0},\ldots,\mathbf{0}) = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{0}) = \{\mathbf{0}\}=W$. The empty set is not the only set that spans $W$.

Comment: @Tegernako $T: v\mapsto 0$ for all $v$.

Comment: I see. Basically every set will satisfy what we have, but not the 'then' part. Thanks a lot, cheers for the weekend!